# Run time '424' error Object Required when referencing a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use VBA to calculate the following linear formula: y = 0.0069x + 17.631

My plan was to input a value that I assigned to the cell "PackageWeight", then when a button is clicked the formula yields "DispatchMinutes", or "y".

```
Private Sub TrucksDTButton_Click()

    Dim WeightValue As Double
    Dim MinutesValue As Double

    WeightValue = wsDispatchButtonsSheet.Range("PackageWeight").Value
    MinutesValue = wsDispatchButtonsSheet.Range("DispatchMinutes").Value

    MinutesValue = 0.0069 * WeightValue + 17.631

End Sub
```

When I run the code, it yields the "Run time '

> 424' Error - Object Required".

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: Is `wsDispatchButtonsSheet` a sheet codename?

Comment: Yes! The sheet itself is named DispatchButtonsSheet.

Comment: Which line errors then?

Comment: `The sheet itself is named DispatchButtonsSheet` -  as opposed to `wsDispatchButtonsSheet`? Is there `Option Explicit` on top?

Comment: @BigBen - perhaps it's some strange ritual whereby we have to ask 3 times.

Comment: The line with the error is                                                                     WeightValue = wsDispatchButtonsSheet.Range("PackageWeight").Value

Comment: 1) What is `wsDispatchButtonsSheet`? 2) Has `PackageWeight` correct spelling?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use the actual sheet name since you did not set a variable for the sheet.

```
WeightValue = Sheets("DispatchButtonsSheet").Range("PackageWeight").Value
```

Comment: Each sheet has a codename. It acts like a predefined variable of type `Worksheet`, and it's a much better way to refer to sheets from code than using the display name that the user can easily edit.

Comment: @GSerg- can you explain how you came up with that conclusion with the information given to us?

Comment: @Davesexcel not my downvote but I think it was from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522467/run-time-424-error-in-vba-when-attempting-to-use-a-button-to-calculate-a-formu/53522675#comment93915486_53522467) in response to my comment right before. Of course I suspected your answer was the issue all along.